# Redirect all requests to index.php and clean the URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I was wondering if it's possible to redirect all requests to files/directories that do not exist to index.php, and after that clean the url.

So when I go to `www.example.com/test/1` I want it to be redirected (rewrote?) to `www.example.com`

I tried the following and it does correctly load `index.php`, but it still says `www.example.com/test/1` in the URL bar...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Of course I still want my css and js to load properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. If I understand, you want to use this as a way of redirecting a 404 not found?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [R=301,L]
```

Or maybe this without index.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I don't want it to be a way of redirecting a 404. I just want all requests to go to `index.php`, since that's the only file I'm using for this simple web-app. But since I'm using the JS History API, I'm rewriting the URL bar so when users refresh it I want it to reload the app and let them restart.

Comment: The second example worked by the way! Since the project is in a subdirectory I had to rewrite the last sentence!